# Gnuplot plot using command line arguments

Tags: bash, gnuplot

I am using **gnuplot** in version 5.0 in order to plot graphs from Log files which are received from another script. Initially, a script runs which creates the Log files, and inside the same script (upon finishing) a new script which will plot the graphs is executed by receiving some command line arguments.
One of the command line argument for the plotting graph script ($4 specifically) is the path where the data (which will be used by plot command) is located. Upon finishing of execution:

```
line 0: warning: Cannot find or open file "/comperative_data.txt"
```

where the command line argument is not used at all. See the source code of the script below:

```
gnuplot<<EOF
set size 1.0,1.0;
set terminal postscript landscape color "Times-Roman" 14 linewidth 2
set timestamp "%d/%m/%y %H:%M"

set key left top Left noreverse enhanced box linetype -1 linewidth 1.000 sample 4 spacing 1 width 0 height 0 autotitles
set grid back lt 0 lw 1

set xlabel "TCP Window Size (Bytes)"
set ylabel "Average Transfer Speed (KiB/s)
set xtics (131072,262144,524288,1048576,2097152,4194304,8388608,16777216,33554432)
set xtics rotate
set logscale x
set format x "%10.f"
set yrange [0:5000000]
set output "$filename"
set title "$title"

fileLocation=system("echo $4/comperative_data.txt")

plot fileLocation using 1:2 title 'Streams_1' with linespoints, fileLocation using 1:3 title 'Streams_2' with linespoints , fileLocation using 1:4 title 'Streams_4' with linespoints , fileLocation using 1:5 title 'Streams_8' with linespoints , fileLocation using 1:6 title 'Streams_16' with linespoints , fileLocation using 1:7 title 'Streams_32' with linespoints , fileLocation using 1:8 title 'Streams_64' with linespoints
EOF
```

Comment: You forgot a `"` in the line setting the ylabel. Additionally you cannot use your shell variables like that. The `system` call will spawn a new shell which is not aware of your parameters like $4.

Comment: I don't understand why you use system. I think you can directly pass the path to the plot command.

Comment: Yes. Just use `plot $4/comperative_data.txt ...`

Comment: It was , thanks a lot @RamboRamon